# Error in my existing android project

Tags: android

error:

The project was not built due to "Resource already exists on disk: '/Project/bin/default.properties'.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent Project  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: Are you using an IDE for development?

Comment: try refresh project and clean all

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the entire `bin` directory and rebuilding.